# CodeKit unable to compile due to not being able to create a cache folder

Tags: codekit

When attempting to compile JavaScript I get the message, "`Minification failed because CodeKit could not create a cache folder to store files.`". Does anyone know where the cache folder should be created or what permissions should be set. I am on Yosemite using CodeKit 2.1.9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cache folder is added to the project folder.